# Is the Yekaterinburg Train Station close to the city center or not?

Tags: trains, luggage, russia, hostels, yekaterinburg

I am looking for a hostel near the train station. But it seems that most of them are very far away (say, 5km) from the train station.

I have many luggage, so it is preferable to be walking distance.

Comment: You did not specifically asked for this, but it seems there are a few hostels rather close to the rail station. [One](http://rzdhotel.ru/guides/city-hotels/ekb) seems to be right at the station, although I would generally advise you against it as, other things equal, the rail stations are not the safest places in Russia. [Another](http://aurorahostels.ru/products/category/1031837) is also nearby. [2Gis site](http://go.2gis.com/h01tf) is often helpful at this. If you don't speak Russian, try Google translate, although I think that basic info such as email or phone is easily found on these pages

Comment: 5km is not far for a big city. It's couple of metro stations away, that's what I would call close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mark's answer is right, I just want to add some useful references for you. If you are in Russia, you can use the map engine from biggest Russian search provider, Yandex: [Maps.Yandex](https://maps.yandex.ru/54/yekaterinburg/?ll=60.584157%2C56.848921&z=13&text=%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B&sll=60.584157%2C56.848921&sspn=0.190887%2C0.065749&sctx=BgAAAAEAYygGzGxOTkAoHIu3X2lMQF758%2F%2F%2Fbtg%2F81uk6%2BrXwD8EAAAAAAECAxQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANgAAAAHO%2F38%2F) ([in English](https://maps.yandex.com/54/yekaterinburg)). They works perfectly on mobile, so this is quite useful for you. They are similar to GoogleMaps, but are much more detailed for Russian cities. For example, Yekaterinburg:

[image]

Another reason to use such engine is an easy search for anything you need in travel:
[image]

Blue dots are small hotels, blue circles are medium hotels, purple circles are paid advertisers, I think. Green `M` letters are metro-stations so you can easily get to any hotel you need:
[image]

If you interested in some mobile application similar to Maps.Yandex, I recommend you [2Gis](https://2gis.ru/ekaterinburg/search/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B/center/60.571918%2C56.837189/zoom/13). It can get your location and show interesting places around you. I works even without Internet connection, so sometimes is very useful:
[image]

Comment: Only don't you rely on Yandex.Maps outside Russia! https://maps.yandex.ru/?ll=-90.182840%2C9.270768&z=5

Comment: @Andrey Chernyakhovskiy: Yeah, I heard something about plans to make a broader competitor to the Panama canal …

Comment: Any reason not to use Google Maps in this case? It shows pretty much the same information as 2Gis and Yandex in Yekaterinburg.

Comment: GMaps aren't always accurate and may contain outdated information. Alos many firms aren't located on GMaps by themselves, as they don't even know about it. I think, if you can use local references, you should use them.

Answer (score 10):

**Yes**. I only arrived at night and was leaving at like 3pm the next day on a new train, but was able to explore around the river, some of the old streets and beautiful buildings, look for the keyboard sculpture (a bit worn down but geeky), and then stroll along to the station with my bags.

Note that there's also a small metro, so if your hostel is close to the metro it'd help a lot. I stayed in some weird hotel/hostel that seemed to be basically dozens of middle-aged men, but hey, the bed was comfy and it was only one night. Unfortunately I can't remember the name or exact location.

For reference, I had a backpack and a day-pack with me, so wasn't walking too far!

On [this map of the city](https://tools.wmflabs.org/wikivoyage/w/poimap2.php?lat=56.842&lon=60.612&zoom=12&layer=M&lang=en&name=Yekaterinburg) - place locator number 8 is basically where the Central station is, and as you can see, it's very central.

You [can also get around](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Yekaterinburg) by metro, bus, tram, trolley and mashrutka.